# C calculating factorials using functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, return, factorial

So i tried to code a function to output nCr (the combinations of choosing k elements from n elements) but it does not show any output...
I think I am unable to call the function correctly but I think my syntax is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial( int n)
{
    int i, nff, nf[10];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        nf[i]=(n-i);

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
       nf[i+1]*=nf[i];

    nff=nf[n-1]; 
    return nff;
}

int faktorial( int k){
    int i, kff, kf[10];
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        kf[i]=(k-i);

    for(i=0;i<k-1;i++)
       kf[i+1]*=kf[i];

    kff=kf[k-1]; 
    return kff;   
}

int facktorial( int k, int n){
    int i, nkff, nkf[10];
    for(i=0;i<(n-k);i++)
        nkf[i]=(n-k)-i;

    for(i=0;i<(n-k)-1;i++)
       nkf[i+1]*=nkf[i];

    nkff=nkf[(n-k)-1]; 
    return nkff; 
}

int combination( int k, int n)
{
    // this function shall call (make use of) another function factorial()
    int nfa,kfa,nkfa,nCra;
    nfa=factorial(n);
    kfa=faktorial(k);
    nkfa=facktorial(k,n);
    nCra = nfa/(kfa*nkfa);
    return nCra;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, k, nCr;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    nCr=combination (k, n);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You need `printf("%d\n", nCr);` after `nCr=combination (k, n);`

Comment: Your functions `faktorial`, `facktorial`, and `factorial` differ only in names. Why do you need three of them???

Comment: `nfa=factorial(n); kfa=faktorial(k); nkfa=facktorial(k,n);` better written as `nfa=factorial(n); kfa=factorial(k); nkfa=factorial(n-k);`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to output the result when it is returned:

```
printf("%d\n", nCr);
return 0;
```

Another issue, your program will crash if the input is 0 or a number greater than 10, it is better not to use an array to computer factorial.